# How to get location names nearby my current location using api v2 in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which I have to fetch all the location names nearby my current location(lat/long) and all location should come under 1000meter radius.

Right now I am hitting below API URL for this:

**https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?&location=22.724376,75.879668&radius=1000&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyD6Lqfrfx5AEINisuSToz-poqXnwsWSYTY**

And I am getting response every time:

```
 {
       "debug_info" : [],
       "html_attributions" : [],
       "results" : [],
       "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
    }
```

My code:

```
private String makeUrl(double latitude, double longitude,String place) 
{
     StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place    /search/json?");

        if (place.equals("")) {
            urlString.append("&location=");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
            urlString.append(",");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
            urlString.append("&radius=1000");
            //urlString.append("&types="+place);
            urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        } else {
            urlString.append("&location=");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(latitude));
            urlString.append(",");
            urlString.append(Double.toString(longitude));
            urlString.append("&radius=1000");
            //urlString.append("&types="+place);
            urlString.append("&sensor=false&key=" + API_KEY);
        }

        return urlString.toString();
    }

private String getUrlContents(String theUrl) 
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()), 8);
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REQUEST_DENIED` means you are using wrong key. Enable `Places API` and then try.

Also you can use `Browser Key` after you enable `Places API`

Comment: use browser key instead of android app key

Comment: Thanks a lot, Now I am using browse key and it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

```
{
       "debug_info" : [],
       "html_attributions" : [],
       "results" : [],
       "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
    }
```

it's say you're using the wrong kind of key
Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?csw=1#api_key
 for how to get a new API key,